# res.render in Express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am new to ExpressJS

index.js

```
 res.render('welcome', { name : "bleh"});
```

welcome.html

```
<html lang="en">
<body>    
<h1>Welcome</h1>    
<script>
    console.log(name)
</script>    
 </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the value of "name" in my HTML page?

Comment: It depends on which templating engine you are using. See: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: If you use nunjucks then you can print your variable with `{{ name }}` in your html document.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really pass variable to  html with res.render.

You should consider using a template engine (there are many of them : pug, handlebar, nunjucks, ejs .... it's up to you to choose). In this case, you'll be able to pass variable with res.render (@cobaltway sended you the docs in comments)

Another options is to make ajax query in your welcome.html to your express server (which will work as an API).
So you'll have this in your index.js `res.send({name : "bleh"});`